# Millennial media not initializing on unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[image]WHen i try to initialize milennial media it show error. screen shot attached.

`MMSDK.Inititalize(context);` inside activity onCreate();

Comment: Is your activity a normal activity or a NativeActivity?

Comment: MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity

Comment: And it extends what type of activity?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the VerifyError, you must compile all your classes using the same version of Java. Also, once you make a change to a class, then make sure that you re-compile your project from scratch. Finally, if your application makes use of external libraries, verify that you use the appropriate version of every library and of course, consult the corresponding javadocs, in order to be sure that everything is correct.

Was using latest MMSDK version 5 when i used MMSDK version 3 its working fine.